# WSO2 API Manager - Tokens become inactive

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I'm currently deploying the WSO2 API manager solution on Amazon EC2.

After each restart of my instance , I'm facing the following issue : All my access tokens become inactive.

`<ams:code>900904</ams:code><ams:message>Access Token Inactive</ams:message>`

I have already changed the "ApplicationAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod" value to 0 in the identity.xml configuration file (/repository/conf/identity.xml) but it did not prevent my tokens from being inactive.

Is there a way to keep all my generated tokens active after each instance restart?

PS: this error does not occur when I restart my wso2 application without restarting my ec2 instance.

Error log :

> ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /test, version: 1.0.3 with key: bLhh7pDxZ8NYwXz5k09nGO_Udcga
>
> ```
>     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:135)
>     at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:88)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:252)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
>     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:191)
>     at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
>     at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.RESTUtil.processGetAndDeleteRequest(RESTUtil.java:146)
>     at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.DefaultHttpGetProcessor.processGetAndDelete(DefaultHttpGetProcessor.java:464)
>     at org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor.process(NHttpGetProcessor.java:296)
>     at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:272)
>     at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod** defines for how longer the server keeps the AccessToken alive. By default this is 1 hour (3600s), which means you need to generate a new access token when trying after 1 hours. Therefore setting this value to 0 second is wrong and to make the token doesn't expire you need to set this to -1 as,

```
<!-- Default validity period for Access Token in seconds -->
<AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>-1</AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
```

You can refer to WSO2 API Manager documentation in [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Generating+Access+Tokens+to+Invoke+APIs#GeneratingAccessTokenstoInvokeAPIs-Renewingexpiredtokens).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The -1 value for AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod solved all my issues.